# HTML5 Canvas to PNG File

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to convert an HTML5 canvas to an image. This is what I got so far:

```
var tmp_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var dataURL = tmp_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
$('#thumbnail_list').append($('<img/>', { src : dataURL }).addClass('image'));
```

but the problem is that I get this code:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAAEsCAYAAADtt+XCAAAgAElEQVR4nNS6Z1xVaZbvv/c+CVOZc6mYEMlJMZRizgljGRARs6AgOSMGQATBSM5ZyTkoOQkSzJWrp3t6etLt6Z7pmf/c++L7f3EOiBZW2dM9dz73xfdzztl7n3Oe/Txrrd9a69mCTC4gkwvIZAKSTECUBARRQBA+jii+46f.......class="image">
```

I want a normal image path that the user can download!

Any help?

Comment: What you are getting is base64 representation of that canvas to image, I think you would have to covert it to bytes and then save those bytes into an image file that you want.

Comment: You could add a simple prompt to tell the user to right click on the generated thumbnail and hit 'save target as'

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> *Info:* IE10+ doesn't support below method at all. Other people already did the work and implemented cross browser solutions.
>   [This](https://github.com/rndme/download) is one of them.

First, add the generated data URL to the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag.
However on some browsers, this alone will not trigger a download. Instead it will open the linked image in a new page.

**Download dialog for a base64 image:**

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...." class="image" />
```

Based on above example, convert the MIME type of the data URL to this:

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg....">Download</a>
```

By telling the browser that the data are `application/octet-stream`, it will ask you to save it on your hard-disk.

---

**Specifying a filename:**

As [Adi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105514/adi) said in the comments below, there is no standard way to define a filename using this method. But, there are two approaches which might work in some browsers.

A) The `download` attribute introduced by Google Crome

```
<a download="image.png" href="...">
```

B) Defining HTTP headers within the data URL
`headers=Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.png`

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename=image.png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA">
```

This worked at least in some older versions of Opera. 
[Here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2010Feb/0069.html) is some discussion about this.

Looking into the Bug/Feature-Tracking systems of the major browsers shows that defining a filename is quite a big wish of the community. Maybe we will see a cross-browser compatible solution in near future! ;)

---

**Save RAM and CPU ressources:**

If you don't want to bloat the RAM of your visitor's browser, you can also generate the data URL dynamically:

```
<a id="dl" download="Canvas.png">Download Canvas</a>
```

```
function dlCanvas() {
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    this.href = dt;
};
dl.addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

This way, your canvas may still be shown as an image file by your browser.
If you want to increase the probability to open a download dialog, you should extend the function above, so that it does the replacement as shown above:

```
function dlCanvas() {
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    this.href = dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
};
dl.addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

Last, add the HTTP header to make extra sure that most browsers offer a valid filename to you! ;)

---

**FULL EXAMPLE:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

/* FILL CANVAS WITH IMAGE DATA */
function r(ctx, x, y, w, h, c) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.strokeStyle = c;
  ctx.stroke();
}
r(ctx, 0, 0, 32, 32, "black");
r(ctx, 4, 4, 16, 16, "red");
r(ctx, 8, 8, 16, 16, "green");
r(ctx, 12, 12, 16, 16, "blue");

/* REGISTER DOWNLOAD HANDLER */
/* Only convert the canvas to Data URL when the user clicks. 
   This saves RAM and CPU ressources in case this feature is not required. */
function dlCanvas() {
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  /* Change MIME type to trick the browser to downlaod the file instead of displaying it */
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]*/, 'data:application/octet-stream');

  /* In addition to <a>'s "download" attribute, you can define HTTP-style headers */
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:application\/octet-stream/, 'data:application/octet-stream;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename=Canvas.png');

  this.href = dt;
};
document.getElementById("dl").addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="32" height="32"></canvas>
<a id="dl" download="Canvas.png" href="#">Download Canvas</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot specify a file name this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work on Safari Version 7.0.3 (9537.75.14) Mac OS X

Comment: Hi @Moogs, unfortunately, I have no chance to test on a Mac, but I'm always curious ;) Could you provide more details, like: Does the canvas render the three coloured boxes? Do you get output on the error console? Do you get a download dialogue? Anyway, Safari _7.0.3 is exactly one year old_. Officially, there is no full HTML5 support for Safari <7.1.

Comment: @Nippey the canvas renders the same on chrome and safari. The only difference is clicking on download link in safari does nothing, and the link disappears. No console errors.

Comment: When you say the link disappears, you mean the formatting? This gives a hint, that an empty string has been assigned. So either .toDataURL returns nothing/unexpected or .replace kills the string. Hm, I really like to dig into such problems, but doing it remote is difficult :)

Comment: @Adi To set a filename just add `this.download = "whatever.png";` as the last line of `dlCanvas` function.

Comment: The code snippet worked on my Safari on MAC - however, the name of the image downloaded shows as unknown. Chrome, however, downloads "Canvas.png"

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes the `download` attribute only works for chromium-based browsers like Chrome and Opera. Other browsers don't seem to support custom file names on Client-Side yet.

Comment: This works for me for Chrome and Firefox. However completely fails on IE11 (Nothing downloaded, no dialog shown).

Comment: Welcome to the World of M$. :) IE10+ don't support above method. There are solutions covering all major browsers like this one: `https://github.com/rndme/download`

Comment: for IE, you can try using msToBlob and msSaveBlob: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28819615/1231466

Comment: When i try to download the canvas image then the image which gets downloaded is broken or damaged

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [reimg](http://github.com/gillyb/reimg) library to convert the canvas to an image object, and even trigger the download for the user.

After you insert the library in your page, just use this :
`ReImg.fromCanvas(yourCanvasElement).downloadPng()`

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 options (both work on almost all browsers):

1- **POST the data to the server**:
On the server you'd have a script that will handle the data and then tell the browser to prompt the user for download.

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=something.png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo base64_decode($_POST['imageData']);
exit;
```

2- **Prompt the user for download using** [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)

```
<div id="clickMe"></div>

Downloadify.create( 'clickMe', {
   data: base64String,
   dataType: 'base64',
   filename: 'something.png'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You might also consider using Concrete.js http://www.concretejs.com, which is a light weight HTML5 Canvas framework that enables peripheral things like this, including downloads.  You would just do this:

```
canvas.download({
  fileName: 'my-file.png'
});
```

and you're done.

Comment: what is that canvas? how to create it ? is it a Concrete object? is it a html element ?how to initialize it to have the download function from your library ? what version of concrete is this? is there a CDN for it?