# Save canvas as jpg to desktop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to save an image (JPEG) to the desktop from an HTML5canvas. I can open in a new window `window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'), "");`, but how can I save it to the desktop? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't choose where to save such a file, though have you made no attempts at this problem?  If you have, please post them.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796513/html5-canvas-to-png-file/12796748#12796748

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### Download attribute

There is a new [download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#search=download%20attribute) in HTML5 that allow you to specify a file-name for links.

I made this for saving canvas. It has a link ("Download as image") -

```
<a id="downloadLnk" download="YourFileName.jpg">Download as image</a>
```

And the function:

```
function download() {
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

You can even change the file-name dynamically by setting the attribute `downloadLnk.download = 'myFilename.jpg'`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/kyjs655r/)** from the archives.

Comment: how can i use this on button event?

Comment: @Rajkamal as I demonstrate in the example (`addEventListener`). When a button is clicked the event handler calls the download function. `this` will be the link itself. The function modifies the href to the data url and since the download *attribute* is specified the browser will allow you to download it instead of showing it (shows a file requester of where you want to save it).

Comment: @Rajkamal Demo added to the answer

Comment: I am new for html5 sorry to asking this u r just giving download link. How can i give this to button <input id="saveBtn" type="button"   onclick="download()"/>

Comment: Thanks for ur help finaly i find out  <a id="saveJpg" download="myImage.jpg" ><input id="saveBtn" type="button"   onclick="download()"/></a>

Comment: @Rajkamal ah! ok, don't use an `input` button. That won't work as you can't set `href` on an input as it isn't available for `input`s. You need to use an `A`-tag as the first code line in my answer. You need to replace the `input` button you have with an `a` link and set the download attribute as shown.

Comment: @Rajkamal you almost got it correct. Just remove the input tag all together. You can set plain text in the a tag instead and use css to style the a link so it looks like the input button.

Comment: it working now  <a id="saveJpg" download="myImage.jpg" onclick="download()"><input id="saveBtn" type="button"   /></a>

Comment: That picture in your fiddle appears to contain all the colours of a good quality migraine!!

Comment: nice but doesnt work in IE 11

Comment: [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/kyjs655r/) is broken

Answer (score 8):

Check this if it helps, A jsfiddle implemented for same requirement.
 http://jsfiddle.net/5whKM/

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"/>

<script>
  var img = document.images[0];
  img.onclick = function() {
    var url = img.src.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
    location.href = url;
  };
</script>
```

Comment: jsfiddle link says not found :(

Answer (score 1):

What you should do in this case, is to send the user `window.location=canvas.toDataURL('png')` to the location of the file you want them to 'download'. So your solution of opening a new windows is what you should do, and is what 'downloading' is.

For example, if you want them to save an EXE for a file, you just let them click on an anchor , and the browser handles requesting the file and downloading it. You can also do that with JavaScript, but it's a security and user-experience problem to just pop SaveAs for the users.

Also check this out: [Browser/HTML Force download of image from src="data:image/jpeg;base64..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64)

Comment: this approach is blocked by CORS policy