# saving an image to a file on local machine

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas

I am writing an image processing algorithm in Javascript and testing it on a html5 based console. i get the image data as the output and i am trying to write a snippet which saves it to a file say `/home/user/Desktop/stegaEncode.png` .

I came to know about `canvas.toDataURL()` function and i cant understand properly what it does . Does it directly encode the image data to a PNG file at the desired source location? Anyways i'm pasting a small snippet of how my code looks to give you a better idea.

```
var imgData =  ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
var encodedImage = new Image(imgData) ;
```

I want to save this new image to a file at the above specified location . What is the best and easy way to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save canvas as jpg to desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397319/save-canvas-as-jpg-to-desktop)

Comment: Because of security reasons, you can't directly save the canvas.toDataURL to your local file system. 

You can draw the canvas image in a new browser tab, then the user can "right-click-save-as" to save the file to the local file system.

        var win=window.open();  
        win.document.write("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");