# how to save the entire html page as jpeg

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this long page.

http://prompter.rareapps.org/prompt/prompt-save.php?p=123

I want to be able to save it as jpeg.

I found this while searching which I believe is the closest match to what I need.
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

The only problem is. It doesn't seem to allow saving the screenshot as jpeg. It takes the screenshot well but it is being appended as "canvas" on the same page.

I need to save my html page in jpeg on click of a button.

Any idea how can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save canvas as jpg to desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397319/save-canvas-as-jpg-to-desktop)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript may be helpful for you.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks. It's not exact duplicate but seeing the duplicate warning on that link you gave stitch everything together. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pure client-side solution, you can just save the contents of canvas generated by html2canvas:

```
var dataURL = document.getElementById("someCanvas").toDataURL("image/jpeg");
document.location.href = dataURL;
```

Comment: This is my code that generate the canvas. How can I reference it using your sample code?
    $('#save-image').click(function () {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
   document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
  allowTaint: true,
  taintTest: false
  });
 });

Comment: @CharlesWayne You'd just put it into your `onrendered` callback, using `canvas` parameter instead of getting it from body (i. e. replace `document.getElementById("someCanvas")` in my example with just `canvas` and you should be ready to go :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use Pageres you can find it here https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres

Comment: Great reference. Looks like it does the job pretty well but it seems it is a shell command not web interface. Sorry for missing that out on my question. I need web interface.

Comment: @CharlesWayne you could use `shell_exec` to run it

Answer (score -1):

i've fiddled around with [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) i'd suggest you'd take a look at it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've seen that but having windows and linux version tells me that it has to be installed on server. (correct me if I am wrong) I have shared host and I cant install anything. Hoping to have something that is standard to most shared host and ready to use.

Answer (score -1):

While it's not exactly a PHP solution, i've used PhantomJS in the past to take "snapshots" of a website from PHP scripts. You can find more information here: http://phantomjs.org/