# Convert Base64 to image file with javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

Does anyone know of any simple javascript that I can use to turn a base64 string into an image (jpg format preferably), so that I can save the image to a file?  This is for a signature pad application.  I can get the signature into a base64 format, but need to save the signature as an image file to use for embedding into a Crystal Report.

Answer (score -4):

I have tried this method in a JSP page to print the image from a base64 string, I guess this should hold good for javascript too. Do not have sample data for now to verify, but here's how I would try it.

```
var oImg=document.createElement("img");
var baseString = null;    //the base64 string you have
var imsc = 'data:image/jpg;base64, '+baseString;
oImg.setAttribute('src', imsc);
document.body.appendChild(oImg);
```

Comment: I have this working so that the new image displays on the page (as in the above example).  What I really need is for the image to save to my computer.  Any ideas on how I can make that part of it work in JavaScript?

Comment: You can convert that base64String to canvas and then download that canvas 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397319/save-canvas-as-jpg-to-desktop
& to convert the data to canvas this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas