# Convert a Base64 into an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var options =
        {
            imageBox: '.imageBox',
            thumbBox: '.thumbBox',
            spinner: '.spinner',
            imgSrc: 'avatar.png'
        }
        var cropper = new cropbox(options);
        document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                options.imgSrc = e.target.result;
                cropper = new cropbox(options);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            this.files = [];
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnCrop').addEventListener('click', function(){
            var img = cropper.getDataURL();            
            document.querySelector('.cropped').innerHTML += '<img src="'+img+'">';
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnZoomIn').addEventListener('click', function(){
            cropper.zoomIn();
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnZoomOut').addEventListener('click', function(){
            cropper.zoomOut();
        })



    };
</script>
```

I downloaded an image cropping tool and it working fine . but it returns a  Base64. I want that to be saved as a image file in the local drive. Help me with the code . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397319/save-canvas-as-jpg-to-desktop

Comment: i cant understand that. please be more specific. @mplungjan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas to PNG File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796513/html5-canvas-to-png-file)

Comment: Add a link : `<a id="downloadLnk" download="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAiAAAAC4CAYAAADaI1cbAAA0h0lEQVR4AezdA5AlPx7A8Zxt27Z9r5PB...">Download as image</a>`

Comment: @haraldK where the image will be stored .

Answer (score 0):

try this code for rendering a base64 data (say `base64_string`) into an image

```
var html = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + base64_string + "'>";
document.body.appendChild( html );
```

also you need to put this code in the `onload` event of the `reader` api

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
       var html = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + event.target.result + "'>";
       document.body.appendChild( html );
   };
```

Comment: in which place the image will be stored @gurvinder

Comment: @ParthibanMK with my code, it will be appended to the body since I don't know where you want to append it. Where do you want it to be stored?

Comment: I want it to be stored as an image file in any of my directory @gurvinder372

Comment: You cannot just store it in your default filesystem. FileSystem API works only in a sandboxed mode. You could use something like that to download a image into your browsers default download directory:

var a = $("<a>").attr("href", "http://www.example.com/some_image.png").attr("download", "img.png").appendTo("body");

a[0].click();

a.remove();