# Download canvas to Image in IE using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, download, html5-canvas

Below  code will convert canvas to image and the same is downloaded in browsers other than IE(I'm using IE9).IE Code opens theDataURL in new tab.But,it is not downloadable.

```
     if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
              {
                  somehtml1= document.createElement("img");
                  somehtml1.id="imgid";somehtml1.name="imgname";
                  somehtml1.src=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                  document.body.appendChild(somehtml1);

                  window.win = open (somehtml1.src);
                   setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("SaveAs")', 500);
                     }           
              else
                       {
                             somehtml= document.createElement("a");
 somehtml.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 somehtml.download = "test.png"; 

}
```

Answer (score 37):

Here's what I'm using - not sure what version of IE this requires as I'm using 11.  It uses a blob for IE and canvas as a dataURL for other browsers.  Tested in Chrome and IE 11.

(canvas is the canvas object, link is an hyperlink object)

```
           if (canvas.msToBlob) { //for IE
                var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'dicomimage.png');
            } else {
                //other browsers
                link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
                link.download = "dicomimage.png";
            }
```

Comment: Any ideas why the image quality isn't as good in IE as with Chrome?

Comment: **Update in 2021:** `Navigator.msSaveBlob` is no longer recommended, and do not use it on production sites. More details can be found on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob)

Comment: In 2021, the code I used this for no longer supports IE, and instead of toDataURL, we are creating a Blob, and then window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), and setting the link.href to point to that.

Answer (score 6):

Fast and Easy for Users: Just open up a new tab displaying the canvas.toDataURL.

Users today are knowledgeable about how to right-click and save.

Trying to push the save-as button for them just creates another potential failure-point in your software. [That's my 2-cents].

Example code:

```
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var html="<p>Right-click on image below and Save-Picture-As</p>";
        html+="<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"' alt='from canvas'/>";
        var tab=window.open();
        tab.document.write(html);
    });
```

**[ Additional solution ]**

You can use the FileSaver.js library to let the user save the canvas to their local drive.

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Hi the requirement is to automatically push the save-as  image ,  once the new tab open.

Comment: Understood...IMHO, it's a bad requirement.

Comment: Yep.Ur Right..But somehow  they need it.

Comment: OK, I've added a script link that can be used to trigger the canvas to be saved to a user's local disk.

Comment: Thanks Mark ...The link U've added works for browser other than IE.Actually i already have a solution to save canvas as image to local disk for browsers other than IE.

Comment: That's all I got :(  Your next step, get firm with your client and assert that that upgrade to IE10 and/or allow the user to right-click-save-as.  As someone who used to do subcontracting for years, I can tell you its important to be able to gently but firmly guide the client towards workable decisions.  Your turn to get firm...go get them!

Comment: Thanks for that point Mark.Will explain client regarding this.

Comment: This answer avoids URL length limits for large images, solving my (related) problem with IE.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save canvas image in IE, CH, FF with the following code in 2019:

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border: 1px solid black">
</canvas>

<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Save Canvas" onclick="saveCanvas()" />

<script>
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(5, 10, 15, 20);
ctx.stroke();

function saveCanvas() {
    if (canvas.msToBlob) { // IE
        blob = canvas.msToBlob();
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'canvas.png');
    } else { // CH, FF
        image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
        window.location.href = image;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```