# MS Edge - window.open gives error "The operation was canceled by the user."

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have two different window.open function calls that are both failing in Microsoft Edge:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("diagramCanvas");
var imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(imgUrl);
```

and

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#results').html()));
```

They both generate the error:

**The operation was canceled by the user.**

This looked like a popup blocker, so I disabled Edge popup blocking and both still fail, while obnoxious popups with real urls do pop up: http://www.popuptest.com/

Is there a way to make Edge open javascript-generated files in a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem may be due to the length of the url in the new window declaration.

I found a workaround based on the answer to this question:

[Download canvas to Image in IE using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860633/download-canvas-to-image-in-ie-using-javascript#21866588)

From the answer:

> Example code:
>
> ```
> $("#save").click(function(){
>     var html="<p>Right-click on image below and Save-Picture-As</p>";
>     html+="<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"' alt='from canvas'/>";
>     var tab=window.open();
>     tab.document.write(html);
> });
> ```

By opening a new window then writing to the body, url length limits can be avoided.

This format works in IE9+ and Edge, as well as Chrome (and should work in all other modern browsers).