# Download a canvas.on a specific file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to download the Canvas as png or jpeg on a specific folder which is on my desk. I read some things about toDataURL, and window location, but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Please share your attempts so far.

Comment: Hi C.attia and welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look at [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about the community and how to ask good questions.

Comment: You can not download to a specific file. You can only download to the clients download directory and the filename may or may not be used depending on the client's preferences. This has more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/12796748/3877726

Comment: Hi all thanks for the reply. I would like to do the travel of one thing on a map. But the picture is still there. So i would like to do something like this : `function Draw(){ saveCanvas(); //save the picture}                                           window.requestAnimationFrame(picture);                                                     function picture(){ ctx.drawImage(picture,x,y,w,h); sleep(125) ; ctx.drawImage (MyCanvas,0,0,w,h);} `