# Download HTML5 Canvas or base64 image from Facebook or Instagram in-app browser

Tags: javascript, html, download, html5-canvas, base64

I try to make a download button to download a canvas or a simple base64 image from html5 opened from Facebook or Instagram app which will open the link into their in-app browser

I find this answer (and a few more) which is working in normal browsers :

[HTML5 Canvas to PNG File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796513/html5-canvas-to-png-file)

but when I open the page from Facebook or Instagram app the download button doesn't work.

Comment: Any errors in the console (F12)? Likely a cross-origin issue from the initial gist but we need to see more code to be able to help you.

Comment: the page is opened in Facebook / Instagram browser which doesn't have a debug tool :(

Comment: the code is the one from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796513/html5-canvas-to-png-file and it's working on normal browsers but when I open the page from fb app I can't download or save the image

Comment: Hi, it's an old question. But I am interested by any solution.

Comment: @Mayhem50 hey, I don't find the code anymore but from what I remember I have found a solution in the end