# how to take the div i created and download it as a png?

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

i created a canvas using javascript and appended it to an output div, i want to take that canvas and download it as a png on client side but i could not find a way to do it

i tried even canva2image but i could not make it work
heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabela"><p>this is a test</p></div>
    <button onclick="takeshot()">Copy</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Define the function  
        // to screenshot the div 
        function takeshot() {
          let div = document.getElementById('tabela');
          html2canvas(div).then(
            function(canvas) {
              document
                .getElementById('output')
                .appendChild(canvas);
              })
        }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can find a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796513/html5-canvas-to-png-file

Answer (score 0):

You can test this.

```js
function handleDownload() {
  const divElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

  html2canvas(divElement).then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = imgData;
    link.download = "div_image.png";
    link.click();
  });
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
  <title>Download Div as PNG</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <h1>Hello, this is the content!</h1>
  </div>

  <button onclick="handleDownload()">Download as PNG</button>
</body>

</html>
```